# Getting [1] "attributes" is required error in node js hapi js application while regsitering hapi-auth-cokkie

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

```
import * as AuthCookie from 'hapi-auth-cookie';
import * as Bell from 'bell';

export function init(configs: IServerConfigurations, database: IDatabase): 
Promise<Hapi.Server> {
    const oauthConfiguration = OAuthConfiguration.getOAuthConfigs();

    return new Promise<Hapi.Server>(resolve => {


        //  Setup Hapi Plugins
        const plugins: string[] = configs.plugins;
        const pluginOptions = {
            database,
            serverConfigs: configs
        };

        const attribute = {
            name: 'authentication',
            version: '1.0.0'
        };


        const authCookieOptions = {
            password: 'cookie-encryption-password', 
            cookie: 'my-auth', // Name of cookie to set
            redirectTo: '/login',
            isSecure: false,
        };

        const pluginPromises = [];

        pluginPromises.push(server.register(Inert));
        pluginPromises.push(server.register(Bell));
        //getting error while registering auth cookie
        pluginPromises.push(server.register(AuthCookie)); 


    });
}
```

I am registering hapi auth cookie in my node js hapi js application. I am able to register inert and bell packages but while registering Hapi auth cookie it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 2):

The error, `[1] "attributes" is required`, indicates that the plugin is compatible with Hapi v17 but an earlier Hapi version is used. To resolve this, you can explicitly install an earlier version of `hapi-auth-cookie`.